# Value of a table in a migration depends on a seeder

Tags: laravel

I have a MeasurementUnits Seeder which generates many measurement units, one of them is Hectare.

I need to create a new migration for a new model that contains an attribute that is measurement_unit_id which must always be the id of the measurement unit that is hectare. Seeders run after migrations so how do I do this if when I run the migrations there are no measurement unit values yet? I understand that in production this is simple because there are already values in the database but not in development.

Comment: It should be easier in Development actually, since you are generally more free to mess with your data in Development vs in Production. If you need code to run based on the existence of database rows, you can do that in a Migration/Seeder; simply query the database for your Hectare `MeasurementUnit`, and if not found, don't do anything. If you need a more specific answer, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77781606/edit) and include more details, i.e. the existing relevant migrations and seeders, etc.

Comment: since the units (data) are needed for your application to function correctly at initiation, then put them in the migration and not the seeder (seeder is generally for random data not specifically needed data)

Comment: I had this "issue" in the past, and as @N69S said, create a seeder that does what you need (sometimes seeders are not random but they put defined data), just run it manually after the table was created (inside the migration itself) because it is a MUST your other (next) migrations to have